# Probability of an n-win season? (Or a binomial distribution with varying probabilities per trial)

Tags: probability

I was wondering if, in a fifteen game football season, I am given the probability of winning each game I can calculate the probability of winning n games in an entire season. Does one just need to brute force this i.e

$$P[n=2] = P[1]P[2] + P[1]P[3]+P[1][4]+...+P[1]P[15]+P[2][3]+P[2][4]...$$

or is there a shortcut? Could I average out the probabilities of winning any given game and use a binomial distribution? This seems like it would be wrong probably.

Comment: Generating function is $\prod_{i=1}^{15}(1-p_i+p_ix)$ - so just read off coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: Your expression for $P(n=2)$ should include the probabilities of not winning $13$ games